# Create user that can have access all tables in Schema1 but just have insert to specific table in Schema2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Please consider this scenario:
I have 2 Schemas: `SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2`

In each schema I have some tables.

I have two logins for each schemas.

I want to create a user that can access (CRUD operation) on all tables in SCHEMA1 but just can Insert in `SCHEMA2.Table1`.

How can I create this user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
USE master
GO

CREATE LOGIN MyLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'xyz';

USE mydb
GO

CREATE USER MyLogin for login MyLogin;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: SCHEMA1 TO MyLogin;

GRANT INSERT ON [SCHEMA2].[Table1] TO MyLogin;
```

Comment: Thanks. 1 more question. Mylogin should have access to just SCHEMA1 objects. Is it necessary to deny access on SCHEMA2 objects before last line?

Comment: @DooDoo, `MyLogin` will only have permissions explicitly granted to the user plus roles the user belongs to, including `public`. An explicit `DENY` is only needed when you want to negate permissions inherited via role membership. A `DENY` is not needed with the script in this answer as long as you have not granted object permissions to the `public` role.